# Send email in plain text, html with input file attachment

Tags: php, email

EDIT:

The basic idea for sending email with PHPmailer was perfect. But I'm having issue attaching files (in different) format.

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "mail.domain.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "frommail@domain.com";
$mail->FromName="fromname";

$mail->AddAddress("admin@domain.com");

$mail->IsHTML(true);

//for file attachments
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "<b>Hi! <br><br> This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.</b>";
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

//$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

I tried to display the sequence but not a help. Much appreciated for your time.

Comment: Sidenote: If this is your actual code, then there cannot be any spaces before `HEADERS;` for your heredoc. Your posted code does contain spaces before it, unless it's just a copy/paste issue here on SO.

Comment: Ok...for sending emails, I would highly suggest using a library (since it makes it easier to tell _what_ needs to be modified/included). I've had success with PHPmailer in the past.

Comment: Don't built your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. They make it utterly trivial.